# how to config git clone with intelliJ behind authentication proxy server

Tags: github, intellij-idea, git-clone

I am new for IntelliJ. I am try to create project from GIT clone but failed due to connection time out. I have do configure **proxy @system settings>http proxy** with authentication and check github clone URL connection successful. but still failed when i try to clone git. I suspect it may affect by others settings which i am not sure.

Comment: Warning: https://twitter.com/githubstatus/status/1016591060024418304

Comment: have you set the proxy in git?

Comment: yes. if you refer to-> choose/check version Control->subversion>network.** use IDEA general proxy settings as default for subversion**

Answer (score 0):

You should not set git proxy in the IDE. Instead, open a terminal and set git proxy config via `git config --global http.proxy http://proxyserver:port`

Answer (score 0):

with authentification u should add credentials

```
$ git config --global http.proxy http://<username>:<userpsw>@<proxy>:<port>
```